# Problems Creating a Javascript function Confim box

Tags: javascript, popup

I'm pretty green at all of this, but trying to create a javascript function that does the following:

1. User clicks on an email
2. A Confirm box appears and user either hits 'ok' or cancel
3. Upon hitting 'ok', they are brought to the email window
4. Upon hitting 'cancel', the window closes

Here's what I have so far and I'm just having an issue with the cancel closing the window. Its acting like the 'ok' button and going to the email window. Thanks so much for any help!!

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    <!--
    function getConfirmation(){
       var retVal = confirm("This is the disclaimer copy to agree or disagree to.");
       if( retVal == true ){
          return true;
       }else{
          return false;
       }
    }
    //-->
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <a href="mailto:test@mywebsite.com" onclick="getConfirmation()">test@mywebsite.com</a>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: This code is nasty: `if( retVal == true ){
          return true;
       }else{
          return false;
       }`

Comment: unrelated to your problem, but please rewrite that function as `return confirm("This is the disclaimer copy to agree or disagree to.");`

Answer (score 1):

you need `onclick="return getConfirmation()">`

mark `return`..

[Jsfiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/QTCNK/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<a href="mailto:test@mywebsite.com" onclick="return getConfirmation()">test@mywebsite.com</a>
```

Add a `return` to the `onclick`.

---

Also you can simplify your function to just:

```
function getConfirmation(){
 return confirm("This is the disclaimer copy to agree or disagree to."); // DONE!
}
```

Comment: Wow thanks so much for the quick responses! When I strip it down to the function above, I'm losing my popup window that has the 'ok' and 'cancel' options.

Comment: @NancyCallen that is because you did not click on the link yet ^_^

Comment: Humm, well I tested it and it just goes directly to the email window and no popup window appears.

Comment: Haha, sorry, you might  need to combine mine and @Rajat's answers :-) updating mine

Comment: I just implemented what @Rajat did and works great! Thanks so much for all your help!!!!